# C# Insert into database, no error and data is not inserted into database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm attempting to insert some data into my local SQL database. The command seems to run successfully and I'm not getting any errors, but for some reason the data is not being inserted into the database. Have I forgotten something?

```
public void RegisterUser(string fName, string lName, string email, string password)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            string saveUser = "INSERT into Users (firstName,lastName,email,password,isAdmin) VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@email,@password,@isAdmin)";

            using (SqlCommand querySaveUser = new SqlCommand(saveUser))
            {
                querySaveUser.Connection = openCon;
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", fName);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lName);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", 1);
                openCon.Open();
                querySaveUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**update:**

SOLVED! I was trying to output to another directory for some reason. Ended up recreating the database which solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
int affected =  querySaveUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and set a debug point and watch affected value.

According to MSDN "If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1."

Comment: Affected returned 0

Answer (score 0):

In case you are debugging a copy of your DB is created in bin/Debug folder, thus you might be checking different DB. Check this - https://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2012/05/dealing-with-local-databases-or-why-your-updates-dont-stick.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I check your code and its working fine in my system but i have changed your connection string so please modified your connection string as mine then check i hope your problem solved

```
public void RegisterUser(string fName, string lName, string email, string password)
    {
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            string saveUser = "INSERT into Users (firstName,lastName,email,password,isAdmin) VALUES (@firstName,@lastName,@email,@password,@isAdmin)";

            using (SqlCommand querySaveUser = new SqlCommand(saveUser))
            {
                querySaveUser.Connection = openCon;
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", fName);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lName);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                querySaveUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isAdmin", 1);
                openCon.Open();
                querySaveUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

Connection String: web.config

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf; Initial Catalog=Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

*It might help someone looking for `Entity Framework Core` or `ASP.NET Zero` related solution.*

In my case I was using `ASP.NET Zero` boiler plate templates for `ASP.NET Core` and it was not inserting into the database. After a few minutes exploration, I found out that `ASP.NET Zero` does not immediately execute the `ef` queries on `db` rather it inserts rows at end of the unit of work.

Usually, it fails to insert if there is an exception it will log that to `Logs` table, you can see the latest logs with exceptions if they were failed.

If you want to execute the queries immediately, you can force it to save changes by calling the `SaveChanges()` method like this:

```
await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```